# Spring boot Caffeine cache not taking unique parameter

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine-cache

I have the following piece of code:

```java
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;

@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "{'myUniqueKey-', #name}")
public String getCacheValue(final String name) {
  return "Hello " + name;
}
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

When I call `getCacheValue` from another class in the following order:

```java
getCacheValue("Brad")
getCacheValue("Emily")
```

The first calls sets the cache and key of `myUniqueKey-Brad` and prints "Hello Brad". The second call also prints "Hello Brad" because it never goes inside the method again. I also tried setting the key this way but still the same issue.

```java
key = "'myUniqueKey-' + #name"
```

Why does the second call not go inside the method? I would think since I have `#name` in the key argument and the name is different, it would print "Hello Emily". What am I doing wrong?